# Could not find the correct Provider . The provider you are trying to read is in a different route

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have following route in my app:

> Main.dart ---> SplashScreen.dart ---> DetailsPage.dart

**Main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => FontSizeHandler()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

From *SplashScreen.dart* I move to *DetailsPage.dart* using  **Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil** i.e

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailsPage()), (route) => false);
```

Now in *Details page* on App Bar there is icon and on press of which I want to change the font using *FontSizeHandler*

**DetailsPage.dart**

```
class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<FontSizeHandler>().increaseFont();
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<FontSizeHandler>().decreaseFont();
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
          ),
        ],
        title: Text(
          "DetailsPage",
          style: GoogleFonts.roboto(),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Card(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 15),
              child: AutoSizeText(
                "MyTexts",
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                  fontSize:
                      context.watch<FontSizeHandler>().fontSize.toDouble(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So the problem here is I am getting this error message

> Could not find the correct Provider This likely
> happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the
> provider

Is this error is due to I used *Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil*?
Though I have **ChangeNotifierProvider** at **top** of hierarchy why is it throwing error?
How to solve this?

**FontSizeHandler.dart**

```
class FontSizeHandler with ChangeNotifier {
  int fontSize = 15;
  void increaseFont() {
    fontSize = fontSize + 2;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void decreaseFont() {
    fontSize = fontSize - 2;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

> **Solved**: The Problem Was With Importing Wrong ChangeNotifier class. Never Trust autoimport again

Answer (score 0):

## Updated Answer

For reference, the issue was caused by an erroneous import as below:

```
import 'file:///.../fontchangehandler.dart'; // import 'package:.../fontchangehandler.dart';
```

## Original Answer

Unfortunately I was unable to reproduce the error that you are experiencing using the provided code. If you could provide the rest of the code from the `DetailsPage` class then that might help to further diagnose the error. I was able to get the example below working which hopefully you might find useful:

```
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<FontSizeHandler>(
          create: (context) {
            return FontSizeHandler();
          },
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class FontSizeHandler extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _fontSize = 15;

  int get fontSize => _fontSize;

  void increaseFont() {
    _fontSize = _fontSize + 2;

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void decreaseFont() {
    _fontSize = _fontSize - 2;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return DetailsPage();
                },
              ),
              (route) => false,
            );
          },
          child: Text('GO TO DETAILS'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<FontSizeHandler>().increaseFont();
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<FontSizeHandler>().decreaseFont();
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
          ),
        ],
        title: Text(
          "DetailsPage",
          style: GoogleFonts.roboto(),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Card(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 15),
              child: AutoSizeText(
                "MyTexts",
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                  fontSize: context.watch<FontSizeHandler>().fontSize.toDouble(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the details page code.
I did the same as you showed above but it is not working.
One more thing this details page comes after some previous page I didnt mentioned that.
Is that this causing issue?

Comment: It might be causing an issue, could you let me know if running the updated code in my example in isolation gives you the same error that you mention in the question? If it does not, could you show me the previous page if possible?

Comment: Yes your code is working fine in isolation..
And yours code is same as what I am doing.

Comment: Thank you for running my complete example in isolation, is there any chance that you could add your code for the previous page to the question? Alternatively, would you be willing to share a link to the project if it is hosted online?

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. If you would be happy to mark the answer as accepted, then that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: My reputation are less and not allowing me to do so.Otherwise I would have done already.

Comment: Makes sense, no problem. Glad we managed to resolve the issue, happy fluttering!